# How do I add weight to ab exercises?

Tags: strength-training, abdominals, weights

The question is lucid enough. How do I add weights to ab exercises like bicycle crunches, abdominal crunches, cross arm crunches and other main ab home workouts.

Note - I do my exercises at home, so the weights listed should be anything I could find that's heavy enough. I have a generator tyre. It's quite heavy and I used that to work my biceps.

Comment: Have you tried differing the exercises you're doing? Like raised leg crunches instead of regular ones or hanging leg raises (maybe hanging from one of these pull-up bars if you got one).

Answer (score 2):

Weight vests, wrist & ankle weights, etc. These will allow you to modify weight without modifying form. Instead of you having to hold onto a weight, the weight holds onto you with these training tools.

It’s certainly possible to hold a plate, dumbbell, or resistance band to place additional tension on your abdominal muscles, but these things require you to modify the movement (which isn’t a bad thing, but it’s simply not what the question asks for).